# How to know when a sorting algorithm has finished?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I have developed a very basic implementation of a sorting algorithm in Rust, and it works how I want it to, except for one thing. It is able to take a set of inputs (take [3, 6, 2, 1, 9, 4]) and it will sort it. I have my program printing the new set of outputs after every swap. What I'm wondering is how can I actually know when my sort finished? After it solves it it displays a completed sort and just infinitely hang there.

What I could do is hard-code the expected result in, and then check if the sort matches that, but that is horrible for two reasons: It defeats the entire purpose of the sort, and it is horribly inefficient and requires hard-coded values, no dynamic values can pass through the algorithm then. Here is the simple algorithm:

```
loop {
    for num in 0..(nums.len() - 1) {
        if nums[num] > nums[num + 1] {
            let i = nums[num + 1];

            nums[num + 1] = nums[num];

            nums[num] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like it to do is recognize when it has finished sorting, and `break;` out of my loop, however, once it becomes solved, the program just hangs.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  if you make an entire pass through the list and never have to swap anything during that pass, the list must be correctly ordered.

Comment: After the inner loop has completed the first time you know for sure the last element is the biggest. This means, you can make the inner loop end earlier one element for each of the subsequent runs. As soon as the inner loop would not run at all you are done.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sorry, I shouldv'e clarified in my post. It is a bubble sorting algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration, keep track of whether the array is sorted, then break if it is.

```
let mut sorted = false;
while !sorted {
    sorted = true;
    for num in 0..(nums.len() - 1) {
        if nums[num] > nums[num + 1] {
            let i = nums[num + 1];
            nums[num + 1] = nums[num];
            nums[num] = i;
            sorted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is a O(n^2) sort, so I wouldn't actually use it for anything.